# Go WebAssembly with gRPC Web

Tags: go, grpc, webassembly, grpc-go, grpc-web

I want to make a website using webassembly written mainly in go, and I would like to use grpc protocol, due the web restrictions, I have to use the "web version protocol" of grpc, and it can be compiled to js library, and how can I compile the "web version" in go?
I found this useful to compile: https://github.com/namely/docker-protoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question but I think (!?) you can't yet do this.

There are >2 issues:

1. WASM in the browser is currently unable (!?) to access Web APIs.
2. The only [gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) SDK is JavaScript (and, since WASM in the browser can't access Web APIs, even if you wrote one in Golang, when you compiled apps using it to WASM, the wouldn't work in the browser)

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean for "access web apis", but the syscall/js library for go interacts with the "javascript web api". in fact like you said so the only possible solution is to compile with grpc-web, and then interact with the compiled code in js from go through syscall/js. Soo ugly, but maybe the only solution for now...

Comment: I'm unsure of the terminology but the browser surfaces host|OS functionality for e.g. networking and -- IIUC -- these APIs aren't (yet) surfaced directly to the WASM runtime. I know WASI plans to offer this for standalone WASM but unsure what's planned for the browser. I think we're both agreed though that your WASM app would need to talk back to the JavaScript to achieve the networking (and therefore may as well make the gRPC-Web calls too). This is only my suspicion though, it would be good for someone more familiar with this to respond too.

Comment: yes. Thank you for yor interest

Comment: You're welcome!